# Using Terraform to configure Google Identity Platform never applies changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, identity

Here is my configuration, I am using a service account with the proper permissions. It says the config is applied successfully every time although the changes never apply. If i run 'terraform plan' or 'apply' right afterwards it still shows the same issue.

Also I cannot change the settings in the cloud web UI.

```
data "google_project" "current" {}

resource "google_project_service" "identity_platform" {
  disable_on_destroy = false
  project            = data.google_project.current.project_id
  service            = "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
}

resource "google_project_service" "identitytoolkit" {
  project = data.google_project.current.project_id
  service = "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
}

resource "google_project_service" "google_identity_platform_tenant" {
  project = data.google_project.current.project_id
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
}


resource "google_identity_platform_project_default_config" "default" {
  sign_in {
    allow_duplicate_emails = false

    anonymous {
      enabled = false
    }

    email {
      enabled           = true
      password_required = true
    }

    phone_number {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried adding other permissions, and different terraform configurations.